# SpringBoot App, working fine in Intellij but Debug is failing

Tags: spring-boot, debugging, intellij-idea

I was able to Debug and Run my spring boot application on intellij, until I made some changes in my application-profile.yml. which caused some failures.
I played with some debug options in intellij to figure out the issue.
I corrected the YML and then I was able to run the application fine.

But now when I start my application in Debug, Intellij is not taking new values, Its still failing with old reasons. I can run my application as Run Main class, but not Debug main class.

Seems some caching in intellij,

- I restarted intellij,
- restarted my Machine
- I did maven clean
- Deleted Configuration (Alt_shift+F9 --> EditConfiguration -- deleted the one present)

But still when Debugging, even if Junit or Main Application class, its failing for same reason.
Reading old YML value which
I'm using community addition.

Answer (score 0):

Wasted more than an hour, still dont know the solution, I just deleted .idea folder and .iml file. and reimported the project in intellij.. all worked fine..